# How to compare percentage

Tags: comparisons, percentages

I am making an infographic where I am comparing web traffic. Because the report will be highly visual, I only use short sentences and phrases.

For example, when I want to compare this month's traffic with the previous month, can I say:

"Up by 10% to December"
"Up by 10% to last January"

What do you think, any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Edward

Comment: Comparing percentages is a snake pit of potential problems.

Comment: If you mean _up 10% compared to December_, use _from December_.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use "since" instead of "to"?

"Up by 10% since December"
"Up by 10% since last January"

It depends on exactly what you mean to say.

Also make sure to differentiate between "percent" and "percentage points".

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Basically, I want to say that the website has 10% more visitors compared to the previous month: increased from 6000 to 6600. I would prefer using simple phrases and percentage to catch attention.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about the "percent" versus "percentage points" issue unless your graph is about something that's reported in percentage form (e.g. unemployment rate, interest rates).

Comment: E.g. if unemployment rises from 5.0% to 5.1%, that's 0.1 percentage points, but a 2% increase.

Answer (score 0):

> "Up by 10% to December
>    " Up  by 10% to last January"

I would prefer "through" or "thru"

> "Up by 10% through November" "Up by 10% through last December "

I think this the most common method.
Another way could be to use "up to December" and "up to last January", but there would be an issue with "up" being used in close proximity with "up by  10%".
I would think "through" most satisfactory.

Comment: What about "Increased/up by 10% compared to November"?

Comment: I'm sure that would be fine so long as there is no doubt as to meaning. The bottom line is that you have to be satisfied in how you say it. I got the idea that you wanted the numbers more than words to be the attraction. If that is the case, you could use "up by 10% over November..

Comment: *through* usually is followed by the end of the period being described. This seems to be the opposite of what he wants -- he's expressing a difference between now and a named month in the past.

Comment: I think you may have missed part of my answer